# Parameters in BULK COPY statements in npgsql

Tags: npgsql

I've read the information about BULK COPY page on Npgsql's webpage [here](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html). Yet looking at the BULK COPY `BeginBinaryExport()` and `BeginBinaryImport()` methods, they both take strings.  How would one construct a SQL injection-safe version of a query for `BeginBinaryImport()` that took query parameters, e.g. didn't return all the rows of a table but only the those that passed a certain filter, such as being on a certain date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't currently supported. I've opened issue https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3841 to track this.

In the meantime you'll have to interpolate parameters as strings into the query, and protect against SQL injection yourself.